# How to filter in mongoDB and ignore duplicate field and data

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to filter a user in MongoDB who has both statuses **active** and **renew**
But I got an issue that, when I use this filter `{keys: {$elemMatch: {status: {$in: ["active", "renew"] }}}}`, the result is shown correctly a user has both statuses above but one user has 2 status active and 2 status renew like this:

```
"Keys" : [
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "active"
        },
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "active"
        },
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "renew"
        },
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "renew"
        }
    ],
```

I just want data like this:

```
"Keys" : [
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "active"
        },
        {
            "keyType" : "key1",
            "keyStatus" : "renew"
        }
    ],
```

how can I filter as the second result, please help?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [{$size: {$setIntersection: ["$Keys.keyStatus", ["active", "renew" ]]}}, 2]
      }
  }},
  {$set: {
      Keys: {$reduce: {
          input: "$Keys",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$and: [
                      {$not: {$in: ["$$this.keyStatus", "$$value.keyStatus"]}},
                      {$in: ["$$this.keyStatus", ["active", "renew"]]}
                  ]},
                  ["$$this"],
                  []
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v-gJSxDr3Xc)

Comment: I already check the demo, then it's works okay but there are something more shortly way, because I apply in filter in MongoDB Azure CosmosDB then it's not work for me